# Understanding and Interacting with API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, api, python-requests

I have a basic API installed as my localhost server that does functions such as add camera, star camera, list cameras, snapshot of camera frame, etc.

My problem is after following the documentation I still can't seem to interact with it well and get the response I need. Here is the code I use to log in and get validation token:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import json


base_url = "http://localhostip:8080/api/user/login?"
parameters = {
    "username": username,
    "password": password
}
auth_tok = requests.post(base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)).json()
print(auth_tok)
```

I get the correct documented response with a token, so following the documentation to add camera I need 2 parameters, `URL` and `Name`, so I did:

```
base_url = "http://localhostip:8080/api/camera/add?"

parameters = {

    "url": 'rtsp://192.168.1.23/1', 

    #or video file 
    "url" : '/home/video/sample.mov'

    "name" : 'cam1'

}
r = requests.post(base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters),headers={'Authorization': auth_tok})
```

when I print the response:

```
-print (r)
-print (r.url)
-print(r.status_code)
-print(r.json())
```

I get this:

```
<Response [500]>

http://192.168.0.162:8080/service/api/camera/add?url=rtsp%3A%2F%2Frtsp%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.23&name=cam1

500

{'code': -111, 'message': None}
```

According to documentation the correct url should be like this:

```
http://192.168.0.6:8080/service/api/camera/add?url=rtsp://192.168.1.23&name=cam1
```

and the response should be:

`Response:
{"status":"ok"}`

So why and how to make the URL POST in the correct format, because I suspect this is the issue, the URL has these encoding symbols that may be messing up the request?

When I use the web browser GUI of this API I can add the camera or even a video file to play but I'm trying to do the same with Python so I can do further processing in future.

Comment: Have you printed `base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)` to check that it's the same as what you're using in the browser? Does the documentation indicate what a return code of `-111` means?

Comment: I only found 1 mention of -111 in  documentation referring to `code:-111, Duplicate username` for a "create user" API call. i don't think its related as i still get this message when i type a fake camera ip address.
How do i print the ```base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)?```

Comment: `print(base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters))`?

Comment: sorry asking about how to print because when wrote it i got print error i think from typo.
anyway the print shows the same format as in browser and same format in documentation. but camera is not added

Comment: I wonder, your `auth_tok` is JSON. What format does the "Authorization" header expect? I suspect plain text.

Comment: according to the doc:
```Protocol: HTTP,
Request Method: GET or POST,
Request Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
Response Content-Type: JSON (application/json),
Character Set Format: UTF-8```

Comment: JSON refers to the response type. Can you extract the authorization token from the response and pass it like `headers={'Authorization': auth_tok_str}`, where `auth_tok_str` is a string?

Comment: if i understood correctly i extracted the token and wrote it in headers as string like
`headers={'Authorization': "token string"}`
it shows no errors

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. So your program can get the token string from the `login` response, then pass that as the Authorization header. Problem solved?

Comment: the problem was adding camera with API call not login token.

Comment: `{'code': -111, 'message': None}` is your error response, right? If the URL is exactly the same as in the browser, my expectation is that the problem lies with authentication.

Comment: but the authentication is fine and returns the correct response but beyond that i get error when adding any camera! and that is the problem i am facing.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the name of the API or the documentation?

Comment: Seems you haven't registered for chat. Is this not a publicly-available API?

Comment: @dspencer i edited the question can you check?

Comment: If you think the "encoding symbols" are the problem, have you tried *not* `urlencode`ing them? What happens if you make the requests from another client, e.g. Postman?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried this: `req = requests.post(base_url+parameters,headers ={'Authorization': auth_tok})`
i get error:
`TypeError: must be str, not dict`
I am not good at using Postman and unfortunately i dont know how todo the base64 password encode in Postman.

Comment: That makes sense, you can't just append a dictionary to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you encode the ' / / ' symbol, so, in order to fix that, you need to use another function from urllib, urllib.parse.unquote(), and use as parameter your encoding function urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters):

```
import urllib

parameters = {
    "url": 'rtsp://192.168.1.23/1',
    "name" : 'cam1'
}
```

The results are :

```
print(urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters))
'url=rtsp%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.23%2F1&name=cam1'

print(urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)))
'url=rtsp://192.168.1.23/1&name=cam1'
```

Source https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote

Comment: thank you this managed to fix the format issue but:
`print(req.status_code)` still returns `500` issue
and
`print(req)` returns `<Response [500]>`